# How to make Zend IDE 5.5.1 to not bother about backslashes?

Tags: php, regex, ide, zend-studio

I use Zend IDE and quite often use Analyze code to quickly find undeclared or unused variables. As all PHP developers I also use regular expressions.

So main question is where to set a checkbox or tune config file to disable these warnings:

Bad escape sequence: \s (line NN)

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don’t you just correct the mistyped string declarations. If you have the regular expression `foo\sbar`, write it as:

```
'foo\\sbar'
"foo\\sbar"
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. That would be MY bug, but I'm getting these messages  with something like preg_match("|^a\sb$|is",$a,$b);

Comment: Replace it by `preg_match("|^a\\sb\$|is",$a,$b);` or `preg_match('|^a\\sb$|is'$a,$b);`. (See http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Well... Sadly I was looking like a novice with this question. Working with PHP for 7 years :-) But. I was impressed having [preg_match("|^a\sb$|is","a b",$out)] and [preg_match("|^a\\sb$|is","a b",$out)] working but second one wasn't ague with analyzer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

window->preferences->php->code analyzer->bug->bas escape sequence

Comment: There's no window menu item. I use Zend 5.5.1 where only following File, Edit, Search, Go to, Project, View, Debug, Tools, Help items.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the suggestion from @SMka and worked like a charm. However, for my version of Zend Studio (10.1), the option was:
Window->Preferences->Semantic Analysis Properties

From there, just set "Bad escape sequence in string" to Ignore.

Keep in mind that I'm not suggesting to change it in every case. This was what I wanted because was flagging all my regexp (reg exps. that have been working for years, so no reason to change them because of a warning).

Hope this helps...